# Unable to edit an object inside a function in a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create the login authentication for this website. I'm having trouble redefining 'creds' in the login function.

I suspect it is the way I have defined the object credential.

This is the way the object Credentials are defined:

```
export interface Credential {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
```

This is where the issue arises:

```
import { Credential } from 'src/app/shared/interface/credential';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private app: AppComponent,
              private loginService: LoginAuthService) { }

  username: string;
  password: string;
  copyright: number;
  creds: Credential;
  x;

  ngOnInit() {
    const date = new Date();
    this.copyright = date.getFullYear();
  }

  login(): void {
// tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
    // if (this.username == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin') {
    //   console.log('success');
    //   this.app.toggleLoggedIn();
    //   this.router.navigate(['home']);
    // } else {
    //   alert('Invalid credentials');
    // }
    console.log(this.username); //prints fine
    console.log(this.password); //prints fine
    console.log(this.creds); //prints to undefined idk why
    this.creds.username = this.username;
    this.creds.password = this.password;
    this.x = this.loginService.submitCredentials(this.creds);
    console.log(this.x);
  }
```

LoginComponent.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined
    at LoginComponent.login (login.component.ts:41)

Comment: because you never initialized `creds:Credential` it is technically undefined.  You are unable to set the properties of an undefined variable.  Try: `this.creds = {username: this.username, password: this.password}`

Comment: That's perfect... I thought it would have been initialized through `creds: Credential`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.creds = { username: this.username, password: this.password}
```

Reason:

Stricter TypeScript settings would reveal that `creds: Credentials;` is actually bad practice for TypeScript because it isn't initialized (immediately or in the constructor).  Therefore the object `this.creds` when you reference it in `login()` is technically undefined.  Since undefined variables cannot have properties, you are getting that error.